# Tally Table to insert missing dates between two dates? SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I pieced together the below code from research from the net and my own SQL knowledge (not the greatest).

The table `Table_One` holds data for staff and their working days, what I am trying to do is `INSERT` rows where the dates are missing (non-working days) between two specified dates for each Staff member.

This is as far as I can get, I don't know how to check if the row is missing and if it is, insert the new `row` with the date and the corresponding staff members data.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF object_id('dbo.Tally') is not null drop table dbo.tally
GO
SELECT TOP 10000 IDENTITY(int,1,1) as ID
   INTO dbo.Tally FROM master.dbo.SysColumns
   ALTER table dbo.Tally
   add constraint PK_ID primary key clustered(ID)
GO
select * from dbo.Tally

--Generate Date Range
DECLARE @StartDate  datetime
DECLARE @EndDate datetime
SET @StartDate = '2016/6/1' 
SET @EndDate= '2016/7/1'
SELECT dateadd(DD,ID-1,@StartDate) as [DATE]
   FROM dbo.Tally
   WHERE dateadd(DD,ID-1,@StartDate)<=@EndDate
```

The table looks like this,

```
Staff_ID  |  Date      | Year   | Mon | Day |  First_Name   |  Last_Name  | Section  | Time_Worked
1001      |  2016/6/1  |  2016  |  6  |  1  |  Bill         |  Price      | Level 1  | 2016/6/1 8:30:00.000
1001      |  2016/6/5  |  2016  |  6  |  1  |   Bill        |  Price      | Level 1  | 2016/6/5 8:30:00.000
1001      |  2016/6/9  |  2016  |  6  |  1  |   Bill        |  Price      | Level 1  | 2016/6/9 8:30:00.000
1001      |  2016/6/12 |  2016  |  6  |  1  |   Bill        |  Price      | Level 1  | 2016/6/12 8:30:00.000
1002      |  2016/6/1  |  2016  |  6  |  1  |   Mary        |  Somers     | Level 1  | 2016/6/1 8:30:00.000
1002      |  2016/6/5  |  2016  |  6  |  1  |   Mary        |  Somers     | Level 1  | 2016/6/5 8:30:00.000
1002      |  2016/6/8  |  2016  |  6  |  1  |   Mary        |  Somers     | Level 1  | 2016/6/8 8:30:00.000
1003      |  2016/6/3  |  2016  |  6  |  1  |   Mark        |  Jones      | Level 1  | 2016/6/3 8:30:00.000
1003      |  2016/6/5  |  2016  |  6  |  1  |   Mark        |  Jones      | Level 1  | 2016/6/5 8:30:00.000
```

The first row of data that falls in between each of the two dates for the staff member will be able to be used to fill the columns other than the date column. And each staff member first row of data will not necessarily be the same date.

Eg. 
This staff members first day is two days after the `SET @StartDate = '2016/6/1'` in the query,

```
Staff_ID  |  Date      |  First_Name  |  Last_Name  | Section  | Time_Worked
1003      |  2016/6/3  |  Mark        |  Jones      | Level 1  | 2016/6/3 8:30:00.000
```

But , the other columns will be able to be used to fill the new rows data.

This is the outcome for one staff member from the table above, in this case ,staff No `1001` named `Bill`.

```
Staff_ID  |  Date       |  Year  |  Mon|  Day|  First_Name |  Last_Name  | Section  | Time_Worked
1001      |  2016/6/1   |  2016  |  6  |  1  | Bill        |  Price      | Level 1  | 2016/6/1 8:30:00.000
1001      |  2016/6/2   |  2016  |  6  |  2  | Bill        |  Price      | Level 1  | NULL
1001      |  2016/6/3   |  2016  |  6  |  3  | Bill        |  Price      | Level 1  | NULL
1001      |  2016/6/4   |  2016  |  6  |  4  | Bill        |  Price      | Level 1  | NULL
1001      |  2016/6/5   |  2016  |  6  |  5  | Bill        |  Price      | Level 1  | 2016/6/5 8:30:00.000
1001      |  2016/6/6   |  2016  |  6  |  6  | Bill        |  Price      | Level 1  | NULL
1001      |  2016/6/7   |  2016  |  6  |  7  | Bill        |  Price      | Level 1  | NULL
1001      |  2016/6/8   |  2016  |  6  |  8  | Bill        |  Price      | Level 1  | NULL
1001      |  2016/6/9   |  2016  |  6  |  9  | Bill        |  Price      | Level 1  | 2016/6/9 8:30:00.000
1001      |  2016/6/10  |  2016  |  6  |  10 | Bill        |  Price      | Level 1  | NULL
1001      |  2016/6/11  |  2016  |  6  |  11 | Bill        |  Price      | Level 1  | NULL
1001      |  2016/6/12  |  2016  |  6  |  12 | Bill        |  Price      | Level 1  | 2016/6/12 8:30:00.000
1001      |  2016/6/13  |  2016  |  6  |  13 | Bill        |  Price      | Level 1  | NULL
1001      |  2016/6/14  |  2016  |  6  |  14 | Bill        |  Price      | Level 1  | NULL
1001      |  2016/6/15  |  2016  |  6  |  15 | Bill        |  Price      | Level 1  | NULL
1001      |  2016/6/16  |  2016  |  6  |  16 | Bill        |  Price      | Level 1  | NULL
1001      |  2016/6/17  |  2016  |  6  |  17 | Bill        |  Price      | Level 1  | NULL
1001      |  2016/6/18  |  2016  |  6  |  18 | Bill        |  Price      | Level 1  | NULL
1001      |  2016/6/19  |  2016  |  6  |  19 |  Bill       |  Price      | Level 1  | NULL
1001      |  2016/6/20  |  2016  |  6  |  20 | Bill        |  Price      | Level 1  | NULL
1001      |  2016/6/21  |  2016  |  6  |  21 | Bill        |  Price      | Level 1  | NULL
1001      |  2016/6/22  |  2016  |  6  |  22 | Bill        |  Price      | Level 1  | NULL
1001      |  2016/6/23  |  2016  |  6  |  23 | Bill        |  Price      | Level 1  | NULL
1001      |  2016/6/24  |  2016  |  6  |  24 | Bill        |  Price      | Level 1  | NULL
1001      |  2016/6/25  |  2016  |  6  |  25 | Bill        |  Price      | Level 1  | NULL
1001      |  2016/6/26  |  2016  |  6  |  26 | Bill        |  Price      | Level 1  | NULL
1001      |  2016/6/27  |  2016  |  6  |  27 | Bill        |  Price      | Level 1  | NULL
1001      |  2016/6/28  |  2016  |  6  |  28 | Bill        |  Price      | Level 1  | NULL
1001      |  2016/6/29  |  2016  |  6  |  29  | Bill       |  Price      | Level 1  | NULL
1001      |  2016/6/30  |  2016  |  6  |  30  | Bill       |  Price      | Level 1  | NULL
```

I have a `While Loop` that is working for me and updating the missing records for now, but the performance is terrible.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "a working loop"?

Comment: I have a query that uses a `while loop` that is currently updating the database with missing dates and data. But I have to loop through each staff member for each day in the month and with over 10,000 records it is taking too long.

Comment: You have shown how your data looks like. This is great. Please show us also how the final result should look like. Also, please add a tag with the version of SQL Server.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov, thanks, I have updated to show what the outcome needs to be like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option: (updated [again])
Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your next question)

```
DECLARE @T as TABLE
(
    Staff_ID    int,
    [Date]      date, 
    [Year]      int,
    Mon         int,
    [Day]       int,
    First_Name  varchar(10),
    Last_Name   varchar(10),
    Section     varchar(10), 
    Time_Worked datetime
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1001, '2016-06-01', 2016, 6, 1, 'Bill', 'Price', 'Level 1', '2016-06-01 8:30:00.000'),
(1001, '2016-06-05', 2016, 6, 5, 'Bill', 'Price', 'Level 1', '2016-06-05 8:30:00.000'),
(1001, '2016-06-09', 2016, 6, 9, 'Bill', 'Price', 'Level 1', '2016-06-09 8:30:00.000'),
(1001, '2016-07-05', 2016, 7, 5, 'Bill', 'Price', 'Level 2', '2016-06-12 8:30:00.000'), -- Different month
(1002, '2016-06-01', 2016, 6, 1, 'Mary', 'Somers', 'Level 1', '2016-06-01 8:30:00.000'),
(1002, '2016-06-05', 2016, 6, 5, 'Mary', 'Somers', 'Level 1', '2016-06-05 8:30:00.000'),
(1002, '2016-06-08', 2016, 6, 8, 'Mary', 'Somers', 'Level 1', '2016-06-08 8:30:00.000'),
(1003, '2016-06-03', 2016, 6, 3, 'Mark', 'Jones', 'Level 1', '2016-06-03 8:30:00.000'),
(1003, '2016-06-04', 2016, 6, 4, 'Mark', 'Jones', 'Level 1', '2016-06-05 8:30:00.000')
```

Declare and populate `@StartDate` and `@EndDate`:

```
DECLARE @StartDate  datetime = '2016-06-01',
        @EndDate datetime = '2016-08-01'
```

**The `INSERT...SELECT` statement:** (I've chosen to use a cte so I wouldn't have to write the `dateadd(DD,ID-1,@StartDate)` so many times)

```
;WITH Calendar AS
(
    SELECT dateadd(DD,ID-1,@StartDate) as [Date]
    FROM dbo.Tally
    WHERE dateadd(DD,ID-1,@StartDate) < @EndDate
)

INSERT INTO @T (Staff_ID, [Date], [Year], Mon, [Day], First_Name, Last_Name, Section)
SELECT DISTINCT Staff_ID, C.[Date], Year(C.[Date]), MONTH(C.[Date]), DAY(C.[Date]), First_Name, Last_Name, Section
FROM @T T
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT Cal.[Date]
    FROM Calendar Cal
    WHERE MONTH(Cal.[Date]) = MONTH(T.[Date])
    AND YEAR(Cal.[Date]) = YEAR(T.[Date])
    AND NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM @T T2
        WHERE T.Staff_ID = T2.Staff_ID 
        AND T2.[Date] = Cal.[Date]
    )
) C
```

Verify inserts:

```
SELECT Staff_ID, [Date], [Year], Mon, [Day], First_Name, Last_Name, Section, Time_Worked 
FROM @T 
ORDER BY Staff_ID, [Date]
```

Results:

```
Staff_ID    Date       Year        Mon         Day         First_Name Last_Name  Section    Time_Worked
----------- ---------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -----------------------
1001        2016-06-01 2016        6           1           Bill       Price      Level 1    2016-06-01 08:30:00.000
1001        2016-06-02 2016        6           2           Bill       Price      Level 1    NULL
1001        2016-06-03 2016        6           3           Bill       Price      Level 1    NULL
1001        2016-06-04 2016        6           4           Bill       Price      Level 1    NULL
1001        2016-06-05 2016        6           5           Bill       Price      Level 1    2016-06-05 08:30:00.000
1001        2016-06-06 2016        6           6           Bill       Price      Level 1    NULL
1001        2016-06-07 2016        6           7           Bill       Price      Level 1    NULL
1001        2016-06-08 2016        6           8           Bill       Price      Level 1    NULL
1001        2016-06-09 2016        6           9           Bill       Price      Level 1    2016-06-09 08:30:00.000
1001        2016-06-10 2016        6           10          Bill       Price      Level 1    NULL
1001        2016-06-11 2016        6           11          Bill       Price      Level 1    NULL
1001        2016-06-12 2016        6           12          Bill       Price      Level 1    NULL
1001        2016-06-13 2016        6           13          Bill       Price      Level 1    NULL
1001        2016-06-14 2016        6           14          Bill       Price      Level 1    NULL
1001        2016-06-15 2016        6           15          Bill       Price      Level 1    NULL
1001        2016-06-16 2016        6           16          Bill       Price      Level 1    NULL
1001        2016-06-17 2016        6           17          Bill       Price      Level 1    NULL
1001        2016-06-18 2016        6           18          Bill       Price      Level 1    NULL
1001        2016-06-19 2016        6           19          Bill       Price      Level 1    NULL
1001        2016-06-20 2016        6           20          Bill       Price      Level 1    NULL
1001        2016-06-21 2016        6           21          Bill       Price      Level 1    NULL
1001        2016-06-22 2016        6           22          Bill       Price      Level 1    NULL
1001        2016-06-23 2016        6           23          Bill       Price      Level 1    NULL
1001        2016-06-24 2016        6           24          Bill       Price      Level 1    NULL
1001        2016-06-25 2016        6           25          Bill       Price      Level 1    NULL
1001        2016-06-26 2016        6           26          Bill       Price      Level 1    NULL
1001        2016-06-27 2016        6           27          Bill       Price      Level 1    NULL
1001        2016-06-28 2016        6           28          Bill       Price      Level 1    NULL
1001        2016-06-29 2016        6           29          Bill       Price      Level 1    NULL
1001        2016-06-30 2016        6           30          Bill       Price      Level 1    NULL
1001        2016-07-01 2016        7           1           Bill       Price      Level 2    NULL
1001        2016-07-02 2016        7           2           Bill       Price      Level 2    NULL
1001        2016-07-03 2016        7           3           Bill       Price      Level 2    NULL
1001        2016-07-04 2016        7           4           Bill       Price      Level 2    NULL
1001        2016-07-05 2016        7           5           Bill       Price      Level 2    2016-06-12 08:30:00.000
1001        2016-07-06 2016        7           6           Bill       Price      Level 2    NULL
1001        2016-07-07 2016        7           7           Bill       Price      Level 2    NULL
1001        2016-07-08 2016        7           8           Bill       Price      Level 2    NULL
1001        2016-07-09 2016        7           9           Bill       Price      Level 2    NULL
1001        2016-07-10 2016        7           10          Bill       Price      Level 2    NULL
1001        2016-07-11 2016        7           11          Bill       Price      Level 2    NULL
1001        2016-07-12 2016        7           12          Bill       Price      Level 2    NULL
1001        2016-07-13 2016        7           13          Bill       Price      Level 2    NULL
1001        2016-07-14 2016        7           14          Bill       Price      Level 2    NULL
1001        2016-07-15 2016        7           15          Bill       Price      Level 2    NULL
1001        2016-07-16 2016        7           16          Bill       Price      Level 2    NULL
1001        2016-07-17 2016        7           17          Bill       Price      Level 2    NULL
1001        2016-07-18 2016        7           18          Bill       Price      Level 2    NULL
1001        2016-07-19 2016        7           19          Bill       Price      Level 2    NULL
1001        2016-07-20 2016        7           20          Bill       Price      Level 2    NULL
1001        2016-07-21 2016        7           21          Bill       Price      Level 2    NULL
1001        2016-07-22 2016        7           22          Bill       Price      Level 2    NULL
1001        2016-07-23 2016        7           23          Bill       Price      Level 2    NULL
1001        2016-07-24 2016        7           24          Bill       Price      Level 2    NULL
1001        2016-07-25 2016        7           25          Bill       Price      Level 2    NULL
1001        2016-07-26 2016        7           26          Bill       Price      Level 2    NULL
1001        2016-07-27 2016        7           27          Bill       Price      Level 2    NULL
1001        2016-07-28 2016        7           28          Bill       Price      Level 2    NULL
1001        2016-07-29 2016        7           29          Bill       Price      Level 2    NULL
1001        2016-07-30 2016        7           30          Bill       Price      Level 2    NULL
1001        2016-07-31 2016        7           31          Bill       Price      Level 2    NULL
1002        2016-06-01 2016        6           1           Mary       Somers     Level 1    2016-06-01 08:30:00.000
1002        2016-06-02 2016        6           2           Mary       Somers     Level 1    NULL
1002        2016-06-03 2016        6           3           Mary       Somers     Level 1    NULL
1002        2016-06-04 2016        6           4           Mary       Somers     Level 1    NULL
1002        2016-06-05 2016        6           5           Mary       Somers     Level 1    2016-06-05 08:30:00.000
1002        2016-06-06 2016        6           6           Mary       Somers     Level 1    NULL
1002        2016-06-07 2016        6           7           Mary       Somers     Level 1    NULL
1002        2016-06-08 2016        6           8           Mary       Somers     Level 1    2016-06-08 08:30:00.000
1002        2016-06-09 2016        6           9           Mary       Somers     Level 1    NULL
1002        2016-06-10 2016        6           10          Mary       Somers     Level 1    NULL
1002        2016-06-11 2016        6           11          Mary       Somers     Level 1    NULL
1002        2016-06-12 2016        6           12          Mary       Somers     Level 1    NULL
1002        2016-06-13 2016        6           13          Mary       Somers     Level 1    NULL
1002        2016-06-14 2016        6           14          Mary       Somers     Level 1    NULL
1002        2016-06-15 2016        6           15          Mary       Somers     Level 1    NULL
1002        2016-06-16 2016        6           16          Mary       Somers     Level 1    NULL
1002        2016-06-17 2016        6           17          Mary       Somers     Level 1    NULL
1002        2016-06-18 2016        6           18          Mary       Somers     Level 1    NULL
1002        2016-06-19 2016        6           19          Mary       Somers     Level 1    NULL
1002        2016-06-20 2016        6           20          Mary       Somers     Level 1    NULL
1002        2016-06-21 2016        6           21          Mary       Somers     Level 1    NULL
1002        2016-06-22 2016        6           22          Mary       Somers     Level 1    NULL
1002        2016-06-23 2016        6           23          Mary       Somers     Level 1    NULL
1002        2016-06-24 2016        6           24          Mary       Somers     Level 1    NULL
1002        2016-06-25 2016        6           25          Mary       Somers     Level 1    NULL
1002        2016-06-26 2016        6           26          Mary       Somers     Level 1    NULL
1002        2016-06-27 2016        6           27          Mary       Somers     Level 1    NULL
1002        2016-06-28 2016        6           28          Mary       Somers     Level 1    NULL
1002        2016-06-29 2016        6           29          Mary       Somers     Level 1    NULL
1002        2016-06-30 2016        6           30          Mary       Somers     Level 1    NULL
1003        2016-06-01 2016        6           1           Mark       Jones      Level 1    NULL
1003        2016-06-02 2016        6           2           Mark       Jones      Level 1    NULL
1003        2016-06-03 2016        6           3           Mark       Jones      Level 1    2016-06-03 08:30:00.000
1003        2016-06-04 2016        6           4           Mark       Jones      Level 1    2016-06-05 08:30:00.000
1003        2016-06-05 2016        6           5           Mark       Jones      Level 1    NULL
1003        2016-06-06 2016        6           6           Mark       Jones      Level 1    NULL
1003        2016-06-07 2016        6           7           Mark       Jones      Level 1    NULL
1003        2016-06-08 2016        6           8           Mark       Jones      Level 1    NULL
1003        2016-06-09 2016        6           9           Mark       Jones      Level 1    NULL
1003        2016-06-10 2016        6           10          Mark       Jones      Level 1    NULL
1003        2016-06-11 2016        6           11          Mark       Jones      Level 1    NULL
1003        2016-06-12 2016        6           12          Mark       Jones      Level 1    NULL
1003        2016-06-13 2016        6           13          Mark       Jones      Level 1    NULL
1003        2016-06-14 2016        6           14          Mark       Jones      Level 1    NULL
1003        2016-06-15 2016        6           15          Mark       Jones      Level 1    NULL
1003        2016-06-16 2016        6           16          Mark       Jones      Level 1    NULL
1003        2016-06-17 2016        6           17          Mark       Jones      Level 1    NULL
1003        2016-06-18 2016        6           18          Mark       Jones      Level 1    NULL
1003        2016-06-19 2016        6           19          Mark       Jones      Level 1    NULL
1003        2016-06-20 2016        6           20          Mark       Jones      Level 1    NULL
1003        2016-06-21 2016        6           21          Mark       Jones      Level 1    NULL
1003        2016-06-22 2016        6           22          Mark       Jones      Level 1    NULL
1003        2016-06-23 2016        6           23          Mark       Jones      Level 1    NULL
1003        2016-06-24 2016        6           24          Mark       Jones      Level 1    NULL
1003        2016-06-25 2016        6           25          Mark       Jones      Level 1    NULL
1003        2016-06-26 2016        6           26          Mark       Jones      Level 1    NULL
1003        2016-06-27 2016        6           27          Mark       Jones      Level 1    NULL
1003        2016-06-28 2016        6           28          Mark       Jones      Level 1    NULL
1003        2016-06-29 2016        6           29          Mark       Jones      Level 1    NULL
1003        2016-06-30 2016        6           30          Mark       Jones      Level 1    NULL
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by 'Verify inserts' Do you place that code directly under the `The INSERT...SELECT statement` in the query window?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. Thanks so much for the help, I will make sure I make a sample data Table next time. Up voted for the great help

Comment: It's just a select statement to make sure the values where inserted correctly to the table. You don't actually need it, it's just a proof that the insert worked as expected.

Comment: "I will make sure I make a sample data Table next time." - you just made my day. seriously. you have no idea the amount of questions I comment with "please add the relevant table ddl and dml for sample data"...

Comment: I had no idea that this was needed, You made my day by informing me that it is needed. Have a great day!

Comment: It's not *required*, but it's very helpful. It just makes the answering process much simpler.

Comment: OK, the problem with this is that it collects the `distinct` data from each column which will not always be the same for the data in between those dates, data can change in each column, So I need to collect data only for the month that is specified.

Comment: So stuff_id 1001 might belong to Bill Price on one month but to another name on another month? or maybe it's the Section that's changes?

Comment: No , `Staff ID`, `First_Name`, `Last_Name` will always be the same, but say for example, `Section` could change to `level 2` for that month. I need to extrapolate that months data only.

Comment: One more question, I have 3 columns that output `year(date)` as `int`, `month(date)` as `int` , and `day(date)` as `int`. I thought I could amend the query to output the rows this way, but your query is too advanced for me. How can I also add those columns values in your query?

Comment: But where do you want them? Your sample data didn't include such columns, and the statement is an onsert statement, you can't add columns that does not belong to the table...

Comment: See updated outcome, I edited my post, The columns were originally there , I thought I could update the code to do this, but you code is is too advanced for me to do that. I am really sorry for this, as I know how much of a pain it is to change everything. Your answer is the best as I can see. and I will mark solved once I get this working.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciated this.

Comment: Unbelievable! Thanks you so much for this.  I tried all morning to get this to work by myself and with this last update of yours, I can finally see what you are doing.  So to get the `NULL` value , you are just leaving it out of the `INSERT` ,Correct?

Comment: Exactly. leaving a column out of the columns list in an insert statement will insert the default value of that column. If it has no default value, it will have a null value.

Comment: Thanks again, now I am going to go back and try to reverse engineer this so I can do it myself in the future. Have a great day.

Comment: Hey, this is working great, adds new rows when there are not any and leaves current ones as is. One more question, first pass with the query to approximately 1000 employees takes about 1800ms, but a second pass when all the data is filled in( I though this should take less time due to all the rows being there), it take over 6000ms. Is this kind of query inherently slow?

Comment: I'm guessing the distinct is causing the query to be slower when there are more records in the table. that being said, 6 seconds is not that slow anyway.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks again for all the help. Cheers

Comment: @ZoharPeled, most likely the self-join of the table to itself makes your approach slow for large tables: `O(n*n)`. `DISTINCT` doesn't help either. I don't quite understand why it is needed.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov you have a solid point there. the distinct is needed because I've tried without it and got multiple records. I didn't try your approach but if it does the same insert in less time then it should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, my answer doesn't care about month boundaries. It cares only about `@StartDate` and `@EndDate`. That extra detail about limiting the expansion of rows to the current month was added later and only in the comments. If the question had been properly edited and sample data contained all important cases to test the query, I could try to adjust my answer. Anyway, it seems that your answer solves the problem (until the table grows large enough), so it is fair for it to be accepted.

Answer (score 3):

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @StartDate date = '2016-06-01';
DECLARE @EndDate   date = '2016-07-01';

DECLARE @Table_One TABLE (
    Staff_ID int, 
    dt date, 
    First_Name nvarchar(50), 
    Last_Name nvarchar(50), 
    Section  nvarchar(50), 
    Time_Worked datetime);

INSERT INTO @Table_One(Staff_ID, dt, First_Name, Last_Name, Section, Time_Worked) 
VALUES
(1001, '2016-06-01', 'Bill', 'Price ', 'Level 1', '2016-06-01 8:30:00.000'),
(1001, '2016-06-05', 'Bill', 'Price ', 'Level 1', '2016-06-05 8:30:00.000'),
(1001, '2016-06-09', 'Bill', 'Price ', 'Level 1', '2016-06-09 8:30:00.000'),
(1001, '2016-06-12', 'Bill', 'Price ', 'Level 1', '2016-06-12 8:30:00.000'),
(1002, '2016-06-01', 'Mary', 'Somers', 'Level 1', '2016-06-01 8:30:00.000'),
(1002, '2016-06-05', 'Mary', 'Somers', 'Level 1', '2016-06-05 8:30:00.000'),
(1002, '2016-06-08', 'Mary', 'Somers', 'Level 1', '2016-06-08 8:30:00.000'),
(1003, '2016-06-03', 'Mark', 'Jones ', 'Level 1', '2016-06-03 8:30:00.000'),
(1003, '2016-06-05', 'Mark', 'Jones ', 'Level 1', '2016-06-05 8:30:00.000');
```

**Query**

Query uses `CROSS APPLY` to "insert" rows when there is a gap in dates. It duplicates the current row as many times as needed using your `Tally` table of numbers.

There is a special handling of the case when the `@StartDate` is before the date of the first row. That's why there are two `SELECTs` unioned together.

The `CTE.PrevDate IS NULL` filters only such rows and they are repeated as many times as needed.

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT *
        ,LAG(dt) OVER (PARTITION BY Staff_ID ORDER BY dt) AS PrevDate
        ,LEAD(dt) OVER (PARTITION BY Staff_ID ORDER BY dt) AS NextDate
    FROM @Table_One AS T
)
SELECT
    Staff_ID
    ,NewDate
    ,First_Name
    ,Last_Name
    ,Section
    ,CASE WHEN NewDate = dt THEN Time_Worked ELSE NULL END AS Time_Worked
FROM
    CTE
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT DATEADD(day, Tally.ID - 1, CTE.dt) AS NewDate
        FROM dbo.Tally
        WHERE Tally.ID <= DATEDIFF(day, CTE.dt, ISNULL(CTE.NextDate, @EndDate))
    ) AS CA_Next

UNION ALL

SELECT
    Staff_ID
    ,NewDate
    ,First_Name
    ,Last_Name
    ,Section
    ,CASE WHEN NewDate = dt THEN Time_Worked ELSE NULL END AS Time_Worked
FROM
    CTE
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT DATEADD(day, - Tally.ID, CTE.dt) AS NewDate
        FROM dbo.Tally
        WHERE Tally.ID <= DATEDIFF(day, @StartDate, CTE.dt)
    ) AS CA_Prev
WHERE 
    CTE.PrevDate IS NULL

ORDER BY Staff_ID, NewDate;
```

**Result**

```
+----------+------------+------------+-----------+---------+-------------------------+
| Staff_ID |  NewDate   | First_Name | Last_Name | Section |       Time_Worked       |
+----------+------------+------------+-----------+---------+-------------------------+
|     1001 | 2016-06-01 | Bill       | Price     | Level 1 | 2016-06-01 08:30:00.000 |
|     1001 | 2016-06-02 | Bill       | Price     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1001 | 2016-06-03 | Bill       | Price     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1001 | 2016-06-04 | Bill       | Price     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1001 | 2016-06-05 | Bill       | Price     | Level 1 | 2016-06-05 08:30:00.000 |
|     1001 | 2016-06-06 | Bill       | Price     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1001 | 2016-06-07 | Bill       | Price     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1001 | 2016-06-08 | Bill       | Price     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1001 | 2016-06-09 | Bill       | Price     | Level 1 | 2016-06-09 08:30:00.000 |
|     1001 | 2016-06-10 | Bill       | Price     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1001 | 2016-06-11 | Bill       | Price     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1001 | 2016-06-12 | Bill       | Price     | Level 1 | 2016-06-12 08:30:00.000 |
|     1001 | 2016-06-13 | Bill       | Price     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1001 | 2016-06-14 | Bill       | Price     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1001 | 2016-06-15 | Bill       | Price     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1001 | 2016-06-16 | Bill       | Price     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1001 | 2016-06-17 | Bill       | Price     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1001 | 2016-06-18 | Bill       | Price     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1001 | 2016-06-19 | Bill       | Price     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1001 | 2016-06-20 | Bill       | Price     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1001 | 2016-06-21 | Bill       | Price     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1001 | 2016-06-22 | Bill       | Price     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1001 | 2016-06-23 | Bill       | Price     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1001 | 2016-06-24 | Bill       | Price     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1001 | 2016-06-25 | Bill       | Price     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1001 | 2016-06-26 | Bill       | Price     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1001 | 2016-06-27 | Bill       | Price     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1001 | 2016-06-28 | Bill       | Price     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1001 | 2016-06-29 | Bill       | Price     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1001 | 2016-06-30 | Bill       | Price     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1002 | 2016-06-01 | Mary       | Somers    | Level 1 | 2016-06-01 08:30:00.000 |
|     1002 | 2016-06-02 | Mary       | Somers    | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1002 | 2016-06-03 | Mary       | Somers    | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1002 | 2016-06-04 | Mary       | Somers    | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1002 | 2016-06-05 | Mary       | Somers    | Level 1 | 2016-06-05 08:30:00.000 |
|     1002 | 2016-06-06 | Mary       | Somers    | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1002 | 2016-06-07 | Mary       | Somers    | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1002 | 2016-06-08 | Mary       | Somers    | Level 1 | 2016-06-08 08:30:00.000 |
|     1002 | 2016-06-09 | Mary       | Somers    | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1002 | 2016-06-10 | Mary       | Somers    | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1002 | 2016-06-11 | Mary       | Somers    | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1002 | 2016-06-12 | Mary       | Somers    | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1002 | 2016-06-13 | Mary       | Somers    | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1002 | 2016-06-14 | Mary       | Somers    | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1002 | 2016-06-15 | Mary       | Somers    | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1002 | 2016-06-16 | Mary       | Somers    | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1002 | 2016-06-17 | Mary       | Somers    | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1002 | 2016-06-18 | Mary       | Somers    | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1002 | 2016-06-19 | Mary       | Somers    | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1002 | 2016-06-20 | Mary       | Somers    | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1002 | 2016-06-21 | Mary       | Somers    | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1002 | 2016-06-22 | Mary       | Somers    | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1002 | 2016-06-23 | Mary       | Somers    | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1002 | 2016-06-24 | Mary       | Somers    | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1002 | 2016-06-25 | Mary       | Somers    | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1002 | 2016-06-26 | Mary       | Somers    | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1002 | 2016-06-27 | Mary       | Somers    | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1002 | 2016-06-28 | Mary       | Somers    | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1002 | 2016-06-29 | Mary       | Somers    | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1002 | 2016-06-30 | Mary       | Somers    | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1003 | 2016-06-01 | Mark       | Jones     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1003 | 2016-06-02 | Mark       | Jones     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1003 | 2016-06-03 | Mark       | Jones     | Level 1 | 2016-06-03 08:30:00.000 |
|     1003 | 2016-06-04 | Mark       | Jones     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1003 | 2016-06-05 | Mark       | Jones     | Level 1 | 2016-06-05 08:30:00.000 |
|     1003 | 2016-06-06 | Mark       | Jones     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1003 | 2016-06-07 | Mark       | Jones     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1003 | 2016-06-08 | Mark       | Jones     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1003 | 2016-06-09 | Mark       | Jones     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1003 | 2016-06-10 | Mark       | Jones     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1003 | 2016-06-11 | Mark       | Jones     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1003 | 2016-06-12 | Mark       | Jones     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1003 | 2016-06-13 | Mark       | Jones     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1003 | 2016-06-14 | Mark       | Jones     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1003 | 2016-06-15 | Mark       | Jones     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1003 | 2016-06-16 | Mark       | Jones     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1003 | 2016-06-17 | Mark       | Jones     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1003 | 2016-06-18 | Mark       | Jones     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1003 | 2016-06-19 | Mark       | Jones     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1003 | 2016-06-20 | Mark       | Jones     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1003 | 2016-06-21 | Mark       | Jones     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1003 | 2016-06-22 | Mark       | Jones     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1003 | 2016-06-23 | Mark       | Jones     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1003 | 2016-06-24 | Mark       | Jones     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1003 | 2016-06-25 | Mark       | Jones     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1003 | 2016-06-26 | Mark       | Jones     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1003 | 2016-06-27 | Mark       | Jones     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1003 | 2016-06-28 | Mark       | Jones     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1003 | 2016-06-29 | Mark       | Jones     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
|     1003 | 2016-06-30 | Mark       | Jones     | Level 1 | NULL                    |
+----------+------------+------------+-----------+---------+-------------------------+
```

### Inserting the generated rows back into the original table

At first I didn't realise that you want to change the original table, so I wrote a `SELECT` query that returns a needed result set. It is easy to adjust it to `INSERT` query that would add new rows into the original table.

All I did is added a filter `WHERE NewDate <> dt`, which ensures that only new rows that didn't exist before are inserted.

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        Staff_ID
        ,dt
        ,First_Name
        ,Last_Name
        ,Section
        ,Time_Worked
        ,LAG(dt) OVER (PARTITION BY Staff_ID ORDER BY dt) AS PrevDate
        ,LEAD(dt) OVER (PARTITION BY Staff_ID ORDER BY dt) AS NextDate
    FROM @Table_One AS T
)
INSERT INTO @Table_One(Staff_ID, dt, First_Name, Last_Name, Section, Time_Worked) 
SELECT
    Staff_ID
    ,NewDate
    ,First_Name
    ,Last_Name
    ,Section
    ,NULL AS Time_Worked
FROM
    CTE
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT DATEADD(day, Tally.ID - 1, CTE.dt) AS NewDate
        FROM dbo.Tally
        WHERE Tally.ID <= DATEDIFF(day, CTE.dt, ISNULL(CTE.NextDate, @EndDate))
    ) AS CA_Next
WHERE
    NewDate <> dt

UNION ALL

SELECT
    Staff_ID
    ,NewDate
    ,First_Name
    ,Last_Name
    ,Section
    ,NULL AS Time_Worked
FROM
    CTE
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT DATEADD(day, - Tally.ID, CTE.dt) AS NewDate
        FROM dbo.Tally
        WHERE Tally.ID <= DATEDIFF(day, @StartDate, CTE.dt)
    ) AS CA_Prev
WHERE 
    CTE.PrevDate IS NULL

ORDER BY Staff_ID, NewDate;
```

**Result**

To check the result just `SELECT` everything from the original table.

```
SELECT * FROM @Table_One ORDER BY Staff_ID, dt;
```

Result is the same as shown above.

Comment: Is it possible to have `Time_Worked ` column as `NULL` for the new rows?

Comment: @KyloRen, yes, just add a `CASE` to compare the dates. I updated the answer.

Comment: Awesome, Up vote for the great help. Let me test everything ,but this looks like the answer. Once I have tested I will mark as the answer. Again , so many thanks for all the help!!!!

Comment: BTW, this is using my `Tally` Table?

Comment: Your query is a bit cumbersome but the answer is good :-). +1 from me as well.

Comment: How do I represent `dt` in the real table? You have `dt` in the sample data. Any Ideas?

Comment: I can't get this to work. The query goes through, but nothing is changed???

Comment: I used the name `dt` for the column instead the name `date` that you used in your example, because `date` is a reserved word and it is not convenient to use reserved words for the names of columns. I didn't realise that you need to change the original table. The query I wrote is a `SELECT` that generates the required output, but it doesn't change the original table. I'll see how it can be adjusted to actually insert the generated rows back into the original table...

Comment: Thanks , that would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try following query

```
DECLARE @Id INT = 1
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2016.06.01'
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '2016.06.30'

;WITH Dates (Id, [Date])
AS(

    SELECT @Id AS Id,  @StartDate AS [Date]

    UNION ALL

    SELECT Id + 1 AS Id , DATEADD(DAY, (Id), @StartDate) AS [Date]
    FROM Dates
    WHERE [Date] < @EndDate
)

SELECT
    Result.Staff_ID,
    Result.Date,
    Result.First_Name,
    Result.Last_Name,
    Result.Section,
    MT.Time_Worked
FROM
(       
    SELECT
        D.[Date],
        A.Staff_ID ,
        A.First_Name ,
        A.Last_Name ,
        A.Section
    FROM 
        Dates D CROSS JOIN 
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT 
                IMT.Staff_ID ,                
                IMT.First_Name ,
                IMT.Last_Name ,
                IMT.Section                 
            FROM 
                MainTable IMT
        ) A
) Result LEFT JOIN  
MainTable MT ON Result.[Date] = MT.dt AND Result.Staff_ID = MT.Staff_ID 
ORDER BY
    Result.Staff_ID,
    Result.[Date]
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this will only work for one staff member? I need it to work for about 5000 + staff members

Comment: Yes, I thought you want this.