# Insert dates between start and end within a Group

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am currently using SQL Server 2008R2.

I have the following data in a table that looks like this:

[[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwmtT.png]]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

This table has 2,000,000 rows of similar patterns.  I have tried joining to a calendar table but the results do not retain the balance information.

I need to be able to add dates between the min and max but also use the last balance value from the previous date (non weekend/non holiday balance).

Comment: Is this example simplified, or does the balance remain constant for each `ID`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tally Table to insert missing dates between two dates? SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38428863/tally-table-to-insert-missing-dates-between-two-dates-sql)