# How can I fetch 0 results from missing row in group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I'm trying various ways on how can I achieve this kind of result:

[image]

The problem is no F from period 202001.

I have created cteTable and left join their common field in main selection but it doesn't give my expected output. Left is the current behavior while right is my expected output. Quantity is number of days from date range (datefrom - dateto) in my cteTable.

```
SELECT GroupID, Gender, COUNT(d) as Quantity, Period
FROM table1
GROUP BY GroupID, Gender, Quantity, Period
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: To ensure every row has a value you need a calendar or tally table where you build a query which returns the required rows, then you join you results on. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38428863/tally-table-to-insert-missing-dates-between-two-dates-sql)

Comment: To translate - you need a "table" of all genders and a "table" of all periods. Cross join those 2 and then outer join that result to your actual table (conveniently named table1 - really?). Now how do you get these 2 tables of all possible values? While you are thinking, start using best practices. Use statement terminators. And usually order of rows is important - so add the appropriate ORDER BY clause.

Comment: And it makes no sense to attempt to GROUP BY quantity as that is the value computed by COUNT (which you aliased to "quantity" - surely you do not also have a column named quantity?). Seems you have more issues since your count (as listed in desired output) should evaluate to 1 for (1234, M, 20201) and not 5. But perhaps you don't want to aggregate at all?

Comment: Thanks man. That is precisely my problem. I asked the question above for a quick posting.

I have this parameters in Main query and I have execquery to create temp calendar table. They have the same monthcount and yearcount. So I am comparing these values in maintable and calendar table.

```
Select * from (
Select 'M' SEX, * from calendartable a
UNION ALL
Select 'F' SEX, * from calendartable b
) calendargender cg
LEFT JOIN --what join should I use?
(select * from maintable) main
ON main.yearcount = cg.yearcount
AND main.monthcount = cg.monthcount
AND main.SEX = cg.SEX
```

Comment: You need to ensure you question contains a [mre] and don't try and put clarifications in comments - thats for us to ask you question. You should edit your clarifications into your question. (Thanks for the translation Smor lol).

Comment: What you have shared above is the grouped results, you got to share the base table data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is how you can do it:

```
select gp.GroupID, g.Gender, gp.Period, COUNT(d) as Quantity
from (values ('M') , ('F')) g(gender)
cross apply (select distinct groupid, period from table1)  gp 
left join table1 t1
on gp.groupid = t1.groupid and gp.period = t1.period and t1.Gender = g.gender
GROUP BY gp.GroupID, g.Gender, gp.Period
```

Comment: Is there a reason you would use `cross apply` rather than `cross join`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff in that case not really , any tip is welcomed

Comment: . . It is just that `cross join` is standard SQL and available in all databases.